# In Javascript, how do I get the serial number of an item in Array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, search, array-map

This is perhaps a very silly question.

I am receiving data from an endpoint in the following format. I want to assign the prediction a serial number taking into account the predictions in the previous category.

```
const items = [{
    "category": "Office",
    "predictions": [
      {
        "id": "2599",
        "value": "Printer",
        "type": "OFF"
      },
      {
        "id": "2853",
        "value": "Camera",
        "type": "OFF"
      },
      {
        "id": "2202",
        "value": "Keyboard",
        "type": "OFF"
      }
    ]
  },
    {
    "category": "Home",
    "predictions": [
      {
        "id": "2899",
        "value": "Television",
        "type": "ELEC"
      },
      {
        "id": "2853",
        "value": "Microwave",
        "type": "ELEC"
      },
      {
        "id": "2732",
        "value": "Washing Machine",
        "type": "ELEC"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

In React, I am doing the following to render the predictions to the customer based on their query:

```
const [highlighted, setHighlighted] = useState(-1);

// other code

const showPredictions = (predictions, categoryIndex) => {
    return (
        <ul role="listbox">
            {predictions.map((prediction, index) => {
                const serialNum = index;
                const isHighlighted = highlighted === serialNum;
                return (
                    <li
                        onMouseEnter={() => handleSuggestionMouseEnter(serialNum)}
                        className={isHighlighted ? 'highlight' : ''}
                    >
                        {prediction.value}
                    </li>
                );
            })}
        </ul>
    );
};

const showPredictionsByCategory = (items) => {
    return items.map((category, catIndex) => {
        const categoryTitle = renderTitleText(category);
        const itemList = showPredictions(category.predictions, catIndex);

        return (
            <div>
                {categoryTitle}
                {itemList}
            </div>
        );
    });
};
```

## **Expectation**:

I want to increment and decrement this serial number so that I can highlight the item on keyup and down. Hence, I want the predictions to be numbered 0, 1, 2, 3,...**n** ( where n = number of predictions minus 1)

So in the above example, the `Office` predictions would have `serialNum` 0, 1, 2 and `Home` predictions would have `serialNum` 3, 4, 5 respectively.

The predictions won't always be 3 per category, they can be any number.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like an accessibility thing. Are you trying to use the keyboard (e.g. up/down arrows) to change which row is selected in the prediction list?

Comment: @toneo yes, that's right! The categories makes it tricky as there's multiple Arrays so possibility of duplicated `highlighted` in both sections. If it were a single Array, I can do it in a straightforward way with the index.

Comment: Personally, I'd use `tabindex` and then bind a `keyup` event to each element, which avoids the whole problem, and it's the "right way" to make something accessible.
That being said.. I don't really like avoiding problems; even if you don't end up using the solution, the journey is still worthwhile.
Perhaps build a flat list of IDs in your "categories" element (no need to invent a new one), then pass your arrow key events upwards, and the selected element downwards.
If that sounds sensible I'll throw you an example you can tailor for your use-case.

Comment: @toneo I have posted a solution I came up with - it won't work for sections more than 2. So I'd be interested to see your example too :)

Comment: Sure thing, I'll get back to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, the problem you want to solve is:

> Allow the user to use the arrow keys to change which item is selected in a list, which is split across three categories.

I'm going to be using three components:

- `<Categories>` to render an array of categories
- `<Category>` to render a single category (array of predictions)
- `<Prediction>` to render a single prediction.

##### Avoid using the array index as an ID

It's not that it's not possible, it's that it sets you up to run into strange bugs later on. Try and uniquely identify each prediction with an ID property of its own. Do the same with your categories.

For example:

```js
const prediction = {
    id: 1,
    name: "Hello, world!"
};

const category = {
    id: 1,
    name: "First category",
    predictions: [prediction]
};
```

##### Flatten the hierarchy to make things easier

You need to know which predictions are before and after the currently-selected prediction. Rather than messing about with some convoluted logic involving categories, take them out of the equation entirely!

You can use the built-in JS function `flatMap` to flatten your categories so you have a big array of predictions to use for your ordering. Then, use React's built-in `useState()` to store the currently-selected index.

```js
const Categories = ({ categories }) => {
    const allItems = categories.flatMap(x => x.predictions);
    const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(0);
    const selectedItem = allItems[selectedIndex];

    return (<div>
        {categories.map(x => <Category key={x.id} name={x.name} predictions={x.predictions} />}
    </div>);
};
```

##### Tell your child components which prediction is selected

`Categories` is currently the only component with any knowledge of the selection, so we need a way to tell the child components (the ones that render predictions) whether they're selected or not.

Pass the ID of the current selection down the chain:

```js
// <Categories>
{categories.map(x => <Category
    key={x.id}
    ...
    selectedId={selectedItem.id} />)}
```

The ID is all you need to identify a single prediction. You don't want to pass `selectedIndex`, you need `allItems` and `categories` to make sense of it and there's no point passing all that stuff down.

##### Tell your predictions how to highlight

If you're passing `selectedId` down the chain this is nice and easy. At this point you can change the default selection ID to confirm the right predictions are being selected.

```js
const Prediction = ({ id, name, selectedId }) => {
    const isSelected = id === selectedId;
    return <li className={isSelected ? "highlight" : ""}>{name}</li>;
};
```

##### Bind the `onKeyUp` event to update the state

Bind the `onKeyUp` event on your `<div>` in `<Categories>` and wire it up to change `selectedIndex`. I've omitted bounds checking for clarity but you definitely want that to avoid going off either end of the array.

```js
const Categories = ({ categories }) => {
    ...
    const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(0);
    const selectedItem = allItems[selectedIndex];

    const onKeyUp = (event) => {
        switch (event.code) {
            case "ArrowUp":
                setSelectedIndex(selectedIndex - 1);
                break;
            case "ArrowDown":
                setSelectedIndex(selectedIndex + 1);
                break;
        }
    };

    return (<div onKeyUp={onKeyUp} tabIndex="-1">
        ...
    </div>);
};
```

`tabIndex="-1"` is needed so that the `div` can receive keyboard events.

##### Putting it all together

Here's a full example, including bounds checking:

```js
// Example data here.
const teeShirts = [
    { id: 1, name: "Black" },
    { id: 2, name: "Red" },
    { id: 3, name: "Blue" },
];

const accessories = [
    { id: 4, name: "Cool Cap" },
    { id: 5, name: "Fancy Tie" },
    { id: 6, name: "Medallion" },
];

const countries = [
    { id: 7, name: "United Kingdom" },
    { id: 8, name: "United States" },
    { id: 9, name: "Australia" },
];

const categories = [
    { id: 1, name: "T-Shirts", predictions: teeShirts },
    { id: 2, name: "Accessories", predictions: accessories },
    { id: 3, name: "Countries", predictions: countries },
];

const Categories = ({ categories }) => {
    const allItems = categories.flatMap((x) => x.predictions);
    const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = React.useState(0);
    const selectedItem = allItems[selectedIndex];

    const onKeyUp = (event) => {
        switch (event.code) {
            case "ArrowUp":
                setSelectedIndex(Math.max(0, selectedIndex - 1));
                break;
            case "ArrowDown":
                setSelectedIndex(
                    Math.min(allItems.length - 1, selectedIndex + 1)
                );
                break;
        }
    };

    return (
        <div onKeyUp={onKeyUp} tabIndex={-1}>
            {categories.map((category) => (
                <Category
                    key={category.name}
                    id={category.id}
                    name={category.name}
                    predictions={category.predictions}
                    selectedId={selectedItem.id}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

const Category = ({ name, predictions, selectedId }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {name}
            <ul role="listbox">
                {predictions.map((prediction) => (
                    <Prediction
                        key={prediction.name}
                        id={prediction.id}
                        name={prediction.name}
                        selectedId={selectedId}
                    />
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};

const Prediction = ({ id, name, selectedId }) => {
    const isSelected = id === selectedId;
    return <li className={isSelected ? "highlight" : ""}>{name}</li>;
};

// This is just bootstrapping so the example works
const App = () => {
    return <Categories categories={categories} />;
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Oh, that's a good idea to use the unique `id` (that comes with the prediction) for highlighting. I assumed that the `selectedIndex` and `selectedId` had to be the same. But I see that does not need be the case. Thanks for your explanation and breaking it down in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'll update here with the solution I went with. **In hindsight, this isn't the solution for more than 2 sections. So if you have a better solution, do tell.**

So what I did was find the starting index for the next section of items with the following logic:

1. Get the total number of predictions (in every category) = `totalCount`
2. Get the number of predictions in the current category = `currentCategroryCount`
3. Subtract `currentCategroryCount` from `totalCount`. This will help in identifying the starting index of the next category of predictions.
4. Pass the value to `showPredictions()`
5. Add this value to the `index`

```
const [highlighted, setHighlighted] = useState(-1);

const showPredictions = (predictions, categoryIndex, numberOfItemsRendered = 0) => {
    return (
        <ul role="listbox">
            {predictions.map((prediction, index) => {
                const serialNum = index + numberOfItemsRendered;
                const isHighlighted = highlighted === serialNum;
                return (
                    <li
                        onMouseEnter={() => handleSuggestionMouseEnter(serialNum)}
                        className={isHighlighted ? 'highlight' : ''}
                    >
                        {prediction.value}
                    </li>
                );
            })}
        </ul>
    );
};

const showPredictionsByCategory = (items) => {
    return items.map((category, catIndex) => {
        const categoryTitle = renderTitleText(category);
        const totalPredictions = getTotalPredictions(items);
        const currentCategroryCount = getCurrentCategoryCount(category);
        const otherSectionCategoryCount = totalPredictions - currentCategroryCount;
// we don't need to the the above calculations for the first section:
        const numOfItemsRendered = catIndex > 0 ? otherSectionCategoryCount : 0
        const itemList = showPredictions(category.predictions, catIndex, numberOfItemsRendered);

        return (
            <div>
                {categoryTitle}
                {itemList}
            </div>
        );
    });
};
```

Comment: This example is missing some of the functions but by the looks of it this can be made to work. I think the problem is `currentCategoryCount`. You need to count all the predictions in the current and all previous categories (up to and including `catIndex`), not just the current category.

Comment: @toneo  I have seen your other answer and it's super useful. I'd be interested in understanding how to improve my current solution, spending a bit more time on it before scratching it. Your comment "_You need to count all the predictions in the current and all previous categories (up to and including `catIndex`), not just the current category._" Can you clarify this statement? And why do I need to include the `catIndex`?

Comment: For each prediction, its index should be: `(number of predictions in previous categories) + (index of this prediction within the current category)`. The first category has no previous categories, so is numbered `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. The second category has one previous category with 5 items, so `[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`. The third adds another 5, so `[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]`.

Comment: You've written `(total number of predictions) - (number of predictions in current category)` which always generates overlapping indices with >1 category. `catIndex > 0` saves your solution for 2 categories because now the first category is forced to start from 0. It's not enough for 3 categories, because the 2nd category won't start at the right place.  
  
Try editing your `showPredictions` component so it outputs `serialNum` onto the page, you should see the same number multiple times which you don't want for IDs!

Comment: @toneo _It's not enough for 3 categories, because the 2nd category won't start at the right place_ Yes, exactly. Hence, why I said that this isn't the solution for more than 2 sections. _For each prediction, its index should be: (number of predictions in previous categories) + (index of this prediction within the current category)_ You're right, but I'm stuck on how to determine the `numOfItemsRendered` i.e. number of predictions in previous categories.

Comment: You want to go through each category in `items`, adding up how many items are in categories that come before the current category. The simplest way is probably a simple for loop. Loop through `items` where `i < catIndex` and add `items[i].length` to get the total.